# How can I retrieve and edit Elementor form names and emails?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, elementor

I am currently using WordPress along with the Elementor plugin. My goal is to remove the email address 'test@test.com' from all forms created using Elementor on my website. You can refer to the field highlighted in this picture:

[image: email]

I attempted to use the following code:

```
function remover_email( $actions, $form ) {
    $actions['emails'] = array_diff( $actions['emails'], array( 'test@test.com' ) );
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'elementor_pro/forms/actions', 'remover_email', 10, 2 );
```

However, it didn't work as expected.

Furthermore, I would like to retrieve the names of all the forms on my website, as shown in this picture:

[image: form_name]

I have tried searching in the database but haven't been successful. Could someone please assist me with this?